# C# WPF: Display child nodes of selected parent node as a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I have a xml like this:

```
<root>
<project name="p1">
 <row field1="31" field2="3" Name="Joe"/>
  <row field1="39" field2="3" Name="Joey"/>
  <row field1="37" field2="3" Name="Joei"/>
</project>
<project name="p2">
 <row field1="31" field2="3" Name="Joe"/>
  <row field1="39" field2="3" Name="Joey"/>
</project>
</root>
```

Now the listbox displays the projects. When a project is selected in listbox, a grid has to display the rows. Is it possible to do this in Xaml? Or should i do it in the code as part of listbox's selectionChanged Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Just name your ListBox, bind the DataGrid's DataContext property to the ListBox's SelectedItem property, then set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to the corresponding xml node.

See the code below.  It uses a ListView, though, instead of a DataGrid.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data">
        <x:XData>
            <root xmlns="">
                <project name="p1">
                    <row field1="31" field2="3" Name="Joe"/>
                    <row field1="39" field2="3" Name="Joey"/>
                    <row field1="37" field2="3" Name="Joei"/>
                </project>
                <project name="p2">
                    <row field1="31" field2="3" Name="Joe"/>
                    <row field1="39" field2="3" Name="Joey"/>
                </project>
            </root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}, XPath=root/project}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListView Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=row}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Field1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@field1}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Field2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@field2}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Field3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Looks great except the datasouce is hardcoded into the XAML. How could you do with an external XML file ?

Comment: Yeah, I did it to make the sample easy to run.  To make it work with an external XML file, simply replace the declaration of the XMLDataProvider to something like:

<XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" Source="XMLFile1.xml"/>

It should still work.

Comment: Thanks. Since .net framework 3.5 is what iam using, i cant use datagrid. Now if row node has multiple subrow nodes, i would have to display each value as a combobox instead of a textblock. This perhaps can be done in DataGrid with each (row,column) being a text block or a combobox, but iam not sure whats the alternative to it